# map() function getting input

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary, input

I'be trying to get an special input from the user and then save it in something like a dictionary. The input I have in mind is something like:

```
>>> id 1230
```

and I want it to be save in the form of:

```
{"id":1230}
```

or

```
[(id,1230)]
```

my problem is that there are actually two variables,one is a string and another is an integer,so somehow I have the get a line from the user,then the first and second parts should be separated and saved in one of the forms I mentioned. I know it has to do with the map() function and maybe a lambda expression is also used.once I used such a code to get two integers:

```
x,y = map(int,input().split())
```

but I really don't know how to do it with a string and integer.
Thank you very much

Comment: You meant `{"id":1230}` or `{id:1230}`?

Comment: Where are you getting the input from, a call to `input`? `map` actually doesn't really apply here.

Comment: @BlackThunder I meant {"id":1230}

Comment: @chepner for instance if you two numbers: x,y = map(int,input().split()) whould work,now I have a string and an integer

Comment: Yes, the fact that you don't want to apply `int` to *every* item resulting from the call to `split` is what makes `map` inapplicable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question about whether you would like to store the data as a `dict` or a list of `tuples` depends on whether you want the user to overwrite existing values or not. If you store the values in a `dict`, the input of

```
id 1230
hi 16
id 99
```

will produce a dictionary like `{"id": 99, "hi":16}` because the second input `id` overwrites the first. A list of tuples approach would produce `[("id", 1230), ("hi", 16), ("id", 90)]`.

How to parse the values has already been suggested by other people, but for completion I will add it to my answer as well.

#### Dict approach

```
d = dict()
var = input('Enter input: ')
key, value = var.split()
d[key] = int(value)
```

#### List approach

```
L = list()
var = input('Enter input: ')
key, value = var.split()
L.append((key, int(value)))
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl you're completely right, I edited it in my answer

Answer (score 5):

You do not need `map` here. You can use `str.split` to split by whitespace and then create a dictionary explicitly:

```
var = input('Enter input: ')  # 'id 1230'
key, value = var.split()
d = {key: int(value)}         # {'id': 1230}
```

You can add some checks to ensure the format is input correctly before proceeding with creating the dictionary:

```
while True:
    try:
        var = input('Enter input: ')  # 'id 1230'
        key, value = var.split()
        d = {key: int(value)}         # {'id': 1230}
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Incorrect format supplied, type "id 1230" expected. Please try again.')
```

Comment: Note that this ignores whatever handling you need to provide in case the user doesn't provide the expected input.

Comment: @jpp thank you very much,but I was curious to know can the code you wrote be compressed in a map()?

Comment: @FarzinNasiri No! `map` applies the same function to *every* element in an iterable; you don't want to do that.

Comment: @FarzinNasiri, I've also added some error-handling to ensure the correct format is supplied.

Answer (score 3):

You need to split the input and save it to a dictionary.

```
data = dict()
keyValue = input()
data[keyValue.split(' ')[0]) = keyValue.split(' ')[1]
```

Comment: `split()` should be preferred over `split(‘ ‘)` since it with split on an arbitrary number of white space characters, as well as handle tabs.

Answer (score 3):

```
usr_inpt = input("enter whatever you want to enter: ")
id, value = usr_inpt.split()
output = [(id,value)]
```

this formats your input into a `tuple` ...but I would not recommend `dictionary`, since every key must be unique and if you have multiple entries from the user, you could end up overwriting previously inputted user inputs.

Comment: `input` always returns a `str`; you don't need to call `str` yourself.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - mostly I do `int(input())` for numbers, didnt occured to me that it is not needed for string input :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
d={}
user_input=input('input id and number separated by space')# 'id 1'
key_value_split=user_input.split(' ')
d[key_value_split[0]]=key_value_split[1] # for dict
print(d) # {'id': '1'}
```

For tuple

```
print(d.items()) # [('id', '1')]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> i = "id"
>>> x = 1234
>>> out = {i:x}
>>> out
{'id': 1234}
>>> out = [(i,x)]
>>> out
[('id', 1234)]
>>> 
>>>
>>> 
>>> ix = input("--> ")

--> id 1234
>>> ix = ix.split()
>>> out = {ix[0]:int(ix[1])}    
>>> out
{'id': 1234}
>>> out = [(ix[0],int(ix[1]))]    
>>> out
[('id', 1234)]
>>>
```

Or maybe a function will work:

```
>>> add = lambda x:{x.split()[0],int(x.split()[1])}
>>> out = add(input("--> "))
--> id 1234
>>> out
{1234, 'id'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Intiatlise value and id
id=0
value=''
id,value=input().split()
id=int(id)
```